# Error in saving related objects in Entity Framework

Tags: wpf, linq, entity-framework, runtime-error

I have a structure like this

`DRDLines`:

```
 ID
 DrawingRevisionID
```

`DrawingRevision`:

```
 ID
 Name
```

They're related in a one-to-many relationship.

In this code example

```
DRDLine line;

using (var db = new AMPX_DCEntities())
{                
    line = db.DRDLines.Single(p => p.ID == 1);  
    System.Console.WriteLine(line.DrawingRevision.ID);
}

using (var db = new AMPX_DCEntities())
{
    var id = 12;
    line.DrawingRevisionID = id;
}

using (var db = new AMPX_DCEntities())
{
    db.Entry(line).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get this error

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'DrawingRevision.ID' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'DRDLine.DrawingRevisionID' on the other end.

What I've found: it doesn't update relations in `DRDLines` inside `DrawingRevision`

Debugging I see:

```
line.DrawingRevision.DRDLines[0].ID != line.DrawingRevisionID
```

If I remove line

```
System.Console.WriteLine(line.DrawingRevision.ID);
```

or write it like this

```
System.Console.WriteLine(line.DrawingRevisionID);
```

everything goes without errors. But I need that line to be used.

So, how can I fix that?

Comment: Is `AMPX_DCEntities` your `DbContext` derived type?

Comment: Yes. It is dervied from DBContext

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is caused by repeatedly creating a new context and then disposing it. When you set the DrawingRevisionID here

```
using (var db = new AMPX_DCEntities())
{
    var id = 12;
    line.DrawingRevisionID = id;
}
```

line is detached from the dbcontext from which it was retreived, but isn't attached to the new DbContext you've created, hence EF won't wire up the relationships when you change the ID.

You could attach the line object back to the context before changing the ID

```
db.DRDLines.Attach(line);
```

That will change both the IDs (although you could just change the other ID manually). Since that context is then disposed, you may need to set the EntityState to Modified for the DrawingRevision (or at least of the ID property) in the last DbContext session.

Also, I would add an Include to the original query to eagerly load the DrawingRevision. At the moment its only loaded when you query the ID on the System.Console line, hence why the behaviour is different. This also causes an extra trip to the database. Putting it into an include will be more efficient and more predictable.

Comment: Thank you for your time. But it doesn't help. I have big application. So, I get data for user to edit, than I save it. It is different parts of programm - load and save. So, yep, it is different contexts. And I have same error, when I'm trying to attach. And yes, if I make something like this             using (var db = new AMPX_DCEntities())
            {
                var id = 12;
                line.DrawingRevision = db.DrawingRevisions.Single(p => p.ID == id);
                line.DrawingRevisionID = id;
            } It works fine...

Comment: But I have many entities linked to DRDLines. So it would be so painful to make those changes to every of them....

Comment: @AnnaSmorodinova There is no silver bullet. You need to either reload or associate the entities you need to work on with the current `DbContext`. (Retro-fitting is a big task, but that is what happens when you find you have a systematic defect in a code base.)